# use image in html from database using django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

when i try display image from my database to html it's won't to show but all rest data are display  ! so what is the error ?

my code

model :

```
class Homepage(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
app_contect = models.CharField(max_length=240,default="")
page_url = models.URLField(max_length=250,default="")
app_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True, blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py :

```
def home_page(request):
app = Homepage.objects.all()
page = request.GET.get('the_home_page', 1) # the_home_page is the name of pages when user go to page 2 etc
paginator = Paginator(app, 6) # 6 that's mean it will show 6 apps in page
try:
    appnum = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    appnum = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    appnum = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request,'html_file/enterface.html', { 'appnum': appnum })
```

Html file :

```
{% for home_page in appnum %}

<label id="label_main_app"> <img id="img_main_app_first_screen" src="{{ home_page.app_image }}" alt="no image found !" height="160" width="165" > {{ home_page.name }} <br><br> <p id="p_size_first_page"> {{ home_page.app_contect}} <br> <br> <a href=" {{ home_page.page_url }} " type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><big> See More & Download </big>  </a> </p>
 </label>


 {% endfor %}
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method in the model class to check if the image exists and has the `.url` attribute or return default image.

`def get_image(self):
    if self.app_image and hasattr(self.app_image, 'url'):
        return self.app_image.url
    else:
        return '/path/to/default/image'`

Then on the template
`{{ home_page.get_image }}`

Another way would be to check for `none` and add default using Django template tags

`{{ home_page.app_image.url|default_if_none:'/path/to/default/image' }}`

Comment: i just edit the 'image' and replace it with 'app_image' and it's work fine !

thanks bro it's work very good thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. I also edited it for those who will need the answer in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To display the image you simply use the tag `{{ home_page.app_image.url }}`.
Note the `.url` at the end.

I would look up the file model in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

If you make the ImageField optional I would recommand checking if it exists first:

```
{% if home_page.app_image %}
    {{ home_page.app_image.url }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: when i try {{ home_page.app_image.url }} 
i got this error 
ValueError at /

The 'app_image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: @KutaibaHMomani Have you uploaded any file? Also is you Media Root settings set properly?

Comment: yes i have uploaded photo and it's in my 'media/images' file 
and yes i have set the properly in settings like this :
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")
MEDIA_URL= "/media/"

Comment: @KutaibaHMomani What Django version you using? I'll check if there have been any updates. However I doubt it. The reason you get `app_image` has no file associated with it is because no file is detected in the model e.g. no image saved with the model. So check your models again and make sure you have saved a image. This is default syntax from Django for the ImageFields, so there must be some typo in your code.

Comment: when i use {{ home_page.app_image}}  this message show to me in atom-terminal 

GET /images/qw.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 5599 (can't load the image )

Comment: oh okay ,, my django version is 2.2.1. 

and how to save image with the model  ?

Comment: @KutaibaHMomani `{{ home_page.app_image }}` wont work as it simply returns the saved model value, not the correct media url. However, is the image qw.jpg inside your media directory?

Comment: @KutaibaHMomani Could you try to add the if statement in the updated answer around your image? This way you can debug what models dont have an image. Are you familiar with the Django admin and saving models?

Comment: okay i will try ,,  i'm new to django
and yes  I'm not very good

Comment: @KutaibaHMomani I would recommand going through the Django tutorial first. This will introduce you to the very basics of the Django framework, what is integrated and whats not.

Comment: okay bro i will try to learn more in django 
because i need more about django really 
anyway i solved this problem just like the other answer 
and thanks a lot for your time really you are good 
thanks again